# _locking msvs 2015

Tags: c, visual-c++

В msvs 2015 функция _locking имеет дефект: если она вызывается с параметром _LK_NBLCK, то при невозможности блокировать заданный участок, функция должна сразу вернуть управление. Однако, она совершает один цикл ожидания длительностью 1000мс. В моем случае это - критично (возникают значительные задержки)
Собственно вопрос, как решить эту проблему (может есть исправление дефекта, или есть возможность использовать какую-то иную функцию).

Comment: На первый взгляд три варианта - использовать другой механизм разделения доступа (например свой), использовать Platform Toolset пониже (v100 к примеру), и самый замороченный вариант - вынести в отдельный проект для студии 2010 библиотеку dll, которая будет заниматься работой с файлами.

Comment: Действительно баг, судя по коду в `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\lowio\locking.cpp:59`. В конце цикла с попытками стоит `Sleep(1000);`, который в любом случае исполняется, даже при одной попытке. Тогда четвертый вариант - скопировать себе в проект код этого лока, поправить и использовать.

Comment: В 2010-м msvs этого бага нет (все тулсеты в 2015 имеют ту же ошибки).
Думал код себе забрать, но там обвязок много - слишком много всего придется загребать.

Comment: Если код не требует фишек c++11, можно в настройках поставить toolset v100, и продолжать в vs2015 работать (пересобрать только разок проект понадобится). Ну и кстати можно совсем простую dll-ку сделать в vs2010, которая только одну эту ф-ию будет экспортировать. И использовать потом в основном проекте её. (рантайм конечно будет нужен от обоих студий в итоге).

Comment: Попробую все-таки сделать свою копию функции. Беда в том, что я не знаю какие там еще баги есть.